# composer global require fails where non global equivalent succeeds

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Im developing a package available at packagist as user/package. Installing it locally works just fine

```
composer require user/package
```

Creating a new project is also fine

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist user/package new-project
```

But the package is to be deployed globally

```
composer global require user/package
```

however this results in the following error log.

> Changed current directory to /home/anders/.composer ./composer.json
>   has been updated Loading composer repositories with package
>   information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your
>   requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for user/package ^v0.0.3 -> satisfiable by user/package[v0.0.3].
>       - Conclusion: remove illuminate/container v5.5.2
>       - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v5.5.2
>       - don't install tightenco/collect v5.4.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.2
>       - don't install laravel/framework v5.5.2|remove tightenco/collect v5.4.33
>       - Installation request for illuminate/container (installed at v5.5.2) -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.5.2],
>   laravel/framework[v5.5.2].
>       - Installation request for tightenco/collect (installed at v5.4.33) -> satisfiable by tightenco/collect[v5.4.33].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

How can this be?

- I have tried `composer global clearcache`
- Deleted a composer.lock file I found directly under /home/anders/.composer/
- Upgraded my dependencies (Laravel) from 5.5.x to 5.6.x with no effect
- Even creating a fresh "laravel new blog" project and uploading to packagist fails with the same error message.

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "user/package",
    "description": "Package",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "ajthinking/tinx": "^2.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "bin": [
        "package"
    ]    
}
```

Would really appreciate help interpreting the error log. Thanks!

### Update

This is the content of /home/anders/.composer/

```
{
    "require": {
        "cpriego/valet-linux": "^2.0",
        "laravel/installer": "^1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.4",
        "phpunit/dbunit": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

Composer version: 1.6.5

Comment: What are the contents of you `/home/anders/.composer/composer.json` file?

Comment: @jrdn Please see updated answer

Comment: It looks like `cpriego/valet-linux` may have installed a lower version of the laravel container (5.1 - 5.3) than your package requires (5.5.*) (Just from checking the [`composer.json`](https://github.com/cpriego/valet-linux/blob/v2.0.24/composer.json) file from  `cpriego/valet-linux`)

Comment: Oboy, im really screwed. Need private dependencies badly. Might try to wrap whole package in an extra folder to keep an "internal" vendors dir triggered by some event. But unfotunately there is no post-require script what I can see. Any other solutions? Package consolidation/cgr looks good but dont want to force that upon users.

Comment: Have you considered using Docker to package everything together away from the rest of the system?

Comment: Yes thats problably the best way, but for this package I cant really asume users will have separate machine setup for each project. For now I will resort to cgr. Thanks alot for your input!

Answer (score 2):

If this is standalone tool, you should consider building [PHAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHAR_(file_format)) for it. You can use [`kherge/box`](https://github.com/box-project/box2) to simplify build process.

PHAR archive is completely standalone, so you'll get rid of all problems with conflicting global dependencies. It may also simplify installation (you need to just download archive and make it executable) for both global and local installation.

Comment: Thanks will definitly examin this path further!